# Display tracert on Google or Bing Maps

Tags: ip-address, google-maps, bing-maps

Is there a program of perhaps website that can display a list of ip-adresses on Google or Bing maps?

For instance, if I do `tracert -d www.youtube.com`, I'll get a bunch of IP-addresses, displaying the path my request travelled.

I'd think it funny to see this on a map, but I find it hard to enter all these IP-addresses manually. Does anybody know a program that can do this?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I reckon the only way to do it would be to manually upload your IP list from your `tracert` and have some script plot it on a Google Map that way. The reason I say this is is if I made a web site where you enter a site to `tracert`, it would do so from that servers IP, and not yours.

Comment: Try this website: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/visual-tracert/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VisualRoute](http://www.visualroute.com/) puts the route on a map, I don't know if there's an application which makes use of Google maps. Will search and update this post.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[traceroute-mapper](https://stefansundin.github.io/traceroute-mapper/) will do this for you

You can paste in the output from `traceroute` on linux/mac or `tracert` on windows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Trace](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/visual-tracert/) works too:

> The visual tracert tool displays the path Internet packets traverse to
>   reach a specified destination. The tool works by identifying the IP
>   addresses of each hop along the way to the destination network
>   address. To get more specific info about an IP address you can use
>   this IP tracer tool from IP-Tracker.org. The estimated geophysical
>   location of each hop is identified using MaxMind's GeoIP database.
>   After all of the hops locations' are identified, the path to the
>   destination is plotted on a Google Map.